# "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception when fetching json file using GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, desktop-application, argumentexception, storagefile

I have a json file in one of the folder of source code which was being fetched using `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` function of `StorageFile` class of C#. This code was working until latest security patch was installed (03 March 2019).

Below is the piece of code :

```
string location = "link to the folder"
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(location));
```

After latest security patch update the above code stopped working resulting in

> Value does not fall within the expected range

Could anyone please let me know the reason for this exception? Has implementation changed after update?

Comment: Have you tried this? var openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

Comment: Nordin, the above code was working file till the latest update. Your suggestion threw an exception

Comment: oke if it's a json file, you should look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/525ff8f2-13f5-4602-bce3-78b909cadedb/how-to-read-and-write-a-json-file-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral hope this helps

Comment: Nordin, I am not using serializing and deserializing, it was working fine before the security patch.